# Quartz next fire time is still previous trigger time?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz with Spring to schedule jobs. I have a job which has been scheduled to run every hour. The problem is that when the scheduled job takes more than an hour then the job's "next fire time" remains the old time and is not fired (since the fire time is already past).

My question is how can we change "next fire time" if the job takes more time than the scheduled time?

Answer (score 1):

Try using @DisallowConcurrentExecution annotation. With this, you can ensure only one instance of your job would execute at one point of time i.e. (only one instance of jobdetail).
Hence, if your job is taking more time than 1 hour then this annotation will stop the 
other instances (i.e other instances will wait until the first running job finishes the execution).

I just guessed ... not sure whether it will work or not.

Comment: You guessed correctly :) One minor correction. It will be only one instance of a jobkey

Comment: Is your problem solved with this ? If yes, can you tell us ,what is the misfire instruction you used in your program ?